# Steam doesn't start libGL errors

Tags: steam

Steam won't start. At first these errors were given:

```
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

But after running these two commands from another question on this site (only the second file existed):

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

the errors have become this:

```
Repairing installation, linking /home/calvin/.steam/steam to /home/calvin/.local/share/Steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 17.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
/home/calvin/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0: undefined symbol: xcb_send_request_with_fds
/home/calvin/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 444: no match: ssfn*
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Following these three steps, Steam launches now from Show Applications list in gnome.

```
/usr/bin/steam --reset
find ~/.local/share/Steam/ \( -name "libgcc_s.so*" -o -name "libstdc++.so*" \) -print -delete
~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the above commands one line at a time, and that seems to have fixed the issue. I was getting a similar error to OP (see below)

```
~$steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```